# Getting PIVOT using GroupBy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

**I have this table:**

```
Person      Job     Day  EndDay
1           101     1    12
1           102     2    11
1           103     3    11
3           101     1    11
3           102     2    11 
3           JobOff  3    11
2           101     1    11
2           102     2    11
2           103     3    11
2           JobOff  4    11
...
```

PS: My days are upto 'N', which I don't know. So, static SQL is not feasible here.

**And I need to change it to this form:**

```
Day (Columns)
Person  (Rows)
Person  1    2    3       4
1       101  102  103     N/A
2       101  102  103     JobOff
3       101  102  JobOff  N/A
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new in SQL.

Thanks to Roman, I have this S.Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] AS
BEGIN

declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt =
    isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
    'isnull(max(case when [Day] = ' + cast([Day_I] as nvarchar(max)) + 
    ' then Job end), ''N/A'') as [' + cast([Day_I] as nvarchar(max)) + ']'
from (select distinct [Day_I] from dbo.Solution) as t
order by [Day_I]

select @stmt = '
select
    Person_I, ' + @stmt +'
from dbo.Solution_Format
group by Person_I'

END
```

But when I am executing this stored procedure like this:

```
exec MyStoredProcedure
```

Its showing me NO results. No errors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    Person,
    isnull(max(case when [Day] = 1 then Job end), 'N/A') as [1],
    isnull(max(case when [Day] = 2 then Job end), 'N/A') as [2],
    isnull(max(case when [Day] = 3 then Job end), 'N/A') as [3],
    isnull(max(case when [Day] = 4 then Job end), 'N/A') as [4]
from Table1
group by Person
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bcf2/16)</kbd>**

it's also possible to do this with dynamic SQL if you need this to arbitrary number of columns:

```
create procedure [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
as
begin   
    declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

    select @stmt =
        isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
        'isnull(max(case when [Day] = ' + cast([Day] as nvarchar(max)) + 
        ' then Job end), ''N/A'') as [' + cast([Day] as nvarchar(max)) + ']'
    from (select distinct [Day] from Table1) as t
    order by [Day]

    select @stmt = '
    select
        Person, ' + @stmt +'
    from Table1
    group by Person'

    exec sp_executesql
        @stmt = @stmt
end
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bcf2/25)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you! However, my days (columns) are up to 63. Is your dynamic solution going to work?

Comment: @RG-3 you've forgot to execute statement - `exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt`

Comment: But, when I am calling this SProc through C#, I dont want to input anything as a param :\

Comment: you don't have to input param. just create procedure without parameters and write the whole statement inside it

Comment: @RomanPekar: Please see my edit in the question. you will get the gist.

Comment: @RG-3 see updated answer - you can't just assign `@stmt` variable, you actually have to execute statement

Comment: Getting this err: Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MyStoredProcedure, Line 0
Procedure sp_MyStoredProcedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37684/discussion-between-roman-pekar-and-rg-3)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use multiple self joins

```
Select
  t1.Person,
  COALESCE(t1.Job, 'N/A') [1],
  COALESCE(t2.Job, 'N/A' )[2],
  COALESCE(t3.Job, 'N/A') [3], 
  COALESCE(t4.Job, 'N/A') [4]
FROM 
  table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table1  t2
  ON t1.Person =  t2.Person
    and t2.Day = 2
  LEFT JOIN table1  t3
   ON t1.Person =  t3.Person
     and t3.Day = 3
  LEFT JOIN table1  t4
    ON t1.Person =  t4.Person
     and t4.Day = 4
WHERE
   t1.Day = 1
ORDER BY 
  t1.Person
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bcf2/30)

Another ways is to use MAX(CASE however I'm not a fan of using aggregates like this.

```
Select
  t1.Person,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Day = 1 then t1.Job END), 'N/A') [1],
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Day = 2 then t1.Job END), 'N/A') [2],
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Day = 3 then t1.Job END), 'N/A') [3],
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Day = 4 then t1.Job END), 'N/A') [4]

FROM 
  table1 t1
GROUP BY
  t1.Person
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bcf2/17)

And lastly there's the pivot clause which I don't really like because of the MAX here

```
SELECT person, 
       COALESCE([1], 'N/A') [1], 
       COALESCE([2], 'N/A') [2], 
       COALESCE([3], 'N/A') [3], 
       COALESCE([4], 'N/A') [4] 
FROM   (SELECT t1.person, 
               t1.day, 
               t1.job 
        FROM   table1 t1) p 
       PIVOT (Max (job) 
             FOR day IN ( [1], 
                          [2], 
                          [3], 
                          [4]) ) AS pvt
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bcf2/27)

Comment: My days (columns) are up to 63 or more...If I move ahead this way, it will be a lot of lines of code.

Comment: @RG-3 Well you can generate the SQL statement easily enough. Whether or  not it get's generated at run time on not should be based on your requirements.